# Apache over-caching JS/CSS/images

Tags: apache-2.2

We have a problem with JS and CSS files being cached for far too long by the browser. We do frequent development, and whenever we push out a change it breaks for some users who have the old version cached. But I can't figure out why our server is caching so hard.

I looked in our httpd.conf and we have this:

```
<IfModule mod_headers>
   <FilesMatch "\.(css|js)$">
     Header set Cache-Control "max-age=43200, public, must-revalidate"
   </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

So, if I'm understanding this right, it *should* be setting JS and CSS files to cache for 12 hours - and even then check the file w/ the server to see if it has changed. But when I inspect the HTTP Response headers I get, I don't even see any Cache-Control headers! But instead of never caching these files, the browser appears to be ALWAYS caching them.

No other headers are set in our conf, and as far as I can tell we aren't even using mod_expires. This is our own server, not some hosted solution, so I have complete control over the box. We don't use .htaccess files so it's not being overridden somewhere these...

I know I'm doing something wrong here. I am pretty sure I have mod_headers installed correctly in apache, but I'm not sure how to check. Should I be using mod_expires instead or in addition? Should I be using a different max-age?

Thanks for any help you guys can provide.

**edit:**
After further experimentation, I've found that the headers do get sent if I comment out the `<IfModule mod_headers>` statement. This is confusing, because if the module wasn't there then the resulting `Header` set wouldn't work either. But sure enough it is working on my development server.

I'm nervous to deploy this as-is to our live server though. Any thoughts on why mod_headers would not be recognized by IfModule, yet still work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all do you have mod_headers loaded?

If you remove the **ifmodule** directives and check for errors with

```
apache2ctl configtest
```

you will see for sure.

Another thing. I do not know you application, but you should consider instead of playing with the caching of these files upload new files. So you replace `your.css` with `your-v1.css` in your html content. (That is what I would do for production sites, what you want to do is ok for a development mode site.)

Comment: I have confirmed that the module is installed, or at least that the configtest comes back with "Syntax Ok". As for renaming files, that isn't a good solution for us.

Comment: Found the culprit. It should be: `<IfModule mod_headers.c>`, not `<IfModule mod_headers>`. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!